# Repeat mechanism in WebClient with Mono

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

My task is to refactor method (code snippet 1) in a way that no combination of for loop and sleep thread is required in repeat / retry logic. To call external api WebClient is used. It is created, configured and registered as Spring bean in a separated method, and I am sure it is working just fine. Let's assume it is autowired and ready to use.

Code snippet 1

```
    public String getSomething() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
            JsonNode response = webClient.get()
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
                    .block();

            if (response.get("something") != null) {
                return response.get("something").asText();
            } else {
                sleep(1_000);
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Number of calls to external api is exceeded");
    }
```

External api serves simple response: when it's ready

Code snippet 2

```
{ "something": "value" }
```

or nothing (no payload) otherwise. Either way response status is 200 OK.
The response is ready (has value) after couple of seconds.

My goal is to create once again GET request and fire it up. What are the options to refactor the method (snippet number 1) so that it keeps the same functionality and remains non reactive ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of the for loop, you should just get a mono from webclient and use Mono.retry() - this also allows for delays, exponential backoff, etc.
2. You should *never* block in the middle of a reactive pipeline. Instead just return the Mono from your request and let the caller handle it.
   This would require the whole module to work reactively. If that's not possible, block the mono after retry.

Comment: Currently, solution does not support reactive workflow and that's why reactive pipeline is blocked and resembles synchronous operation. Unfortunately, criteria for retry lays within response body that can't be accessed in blocking context as I understand and found out.

Comment: Well then just use WebClient.bodyToMono().retry(NUM_OF_RETRIES).block()

Comment: That's not that easy Mono#retry resubscribes on error within pipeline. In my case there is no error it's always 200 OK either with JSON body or none. Repeat criteria are based on response body.

Comment: You can solve this by throwing an exception when receiving an undesired result:  
`WebClient.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
.map(response -> response.get("something").asText())
.retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS, Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
.block()`. 
The map will throw a `NullPointerException` when `response.get()` returns null.

Comment: Again you can't mix up map (asynchronous and initialized lazy) with blocking context. @PatrickHooijer your solution won't work.